# GameCenter: Retrieving scores: null score object?

Tags: iphone, xcode, game-center

My project deals with
 an app using the iPhone Game Center functionalities. As i am learning it, i have used the example from Apple documentation below:

```
- (void) retrieveTopTenScores
{
     GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
     if (leaderboardRequest != nil)
    {
       leaderboardRequest.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
       leaderboardRequest.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;
       leaderboardRequest.identifier = @"Combined.LandMaps"
       leaderboardRequest.range = NSMakeRange(1,10);
       [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil)
        {
            // Handle the error.
        }
        if (scores != nil)
        {
            // Process the score information.
        }
        }];
}
}
```

In principle it works fine : I do get a non-nil Score array; with one GKscore object.

However, this GKScore object is nil even though the Game Center shows that there is one score.

I have tried log-in and out of the game centre to refresh somewhat the score data from the phone GC but i can still see my score of 10.000 (as my own GC login) however every time i attempt retrieving programatically it always return null as score object...

Any tips for me or directions you could point me out?

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine; it looks like there is a refresh time for the Game Center server. Yesterday, the score did appear locally on my phone, but weren't apparently not updated on the Game Center Server. Trying this morning works fine, it looks like the score data was finally updated on the server too; resulting into getting a GKScore which is no longer null.

It's interesting though to realise that when the Game Center server and the iPhone aren't in synch, it still returns non-nil Scores array only GKScore nil result... In case you have several scores in your Game Center, i guess you don't see the nil GKScore but the scores of the past days instead of the most recent.